# How do you use forcat's fct_lump_min() function on a factor while keeping another identifiying factor?

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

Lets consider this dummy dataset:

```
v1<- c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
v2<- c("Z","Y", "X", "X", "V", "U")
Count<- c(2, 5, 10, 5, 1)
df<- cbind.data.frame(v1, v2, Count)
```

I want to use `fct_lump_min()` to lump all v1 factors that have a count of 2 or less into another factor named "unique". If I were to completely disregard the V2 factor column, I have functional code like this:

```
df<-df %>% 
  mutate(CombinedDGSequence = fct_lump_min(v1, 2, Count, other_level = "Unique")) %>% 
  count(CombinedDGSequence, wt = Count, name = "Count")
```

However, doing so removes the corresponding v2 factor column completely. Is there any way I can maintain each v1 factor level's corresponding v2 value in the resulting dataframe after using `fct_lump_min`?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the data shared? Also creating dataframe produces an error `arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 5`

Answer (score 1):

We may need `add_count` which creates a new column instead of summarizing

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>% 
   mutate(CombinedDGSequence = fct_lump_min(v1, 2, Count, 
         other_level = "Unique"))  %>% 
   add_count(CombinedDGSequence, wt = Count, name = "Count")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is largely what I'm looking for! However, now there are multiple v1="Unique" rows, each with a different corresponding V2 factor- is there any way I can lump all of these v1="Unique" rows all into one row/factor, whilst replacing those said rows' v2 factor with an "NA"? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @johnny2554 not clear about your expected ouput.  You may add `%>% distinct(CombinedDGSequence, v1, .keep_all = TRUE)` or do a group by summarise by pasting

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to combine all the `v2` values in one string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  mutate(v1 = fct_lump_min(v1, 2, Count, other_level = "Unique")) %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  summarise(v2 = toString(v2), 
            Count = sum(Count))
```